# Check if onbeforeunload is supported using PHP

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

Is it possible to check onbeforeunload event using PHP.

Comment: Nope, PHP executes on the server.  The client doesn't send that information.  You could make an AJAX call from the client to _tell_ the server if it supports `onbeforeunload`, but the server cannot find out for itself.

Comment: you can't. it's the same as knowing in PHP if the browser has JS or not.

Answer (score 0):

No, the PHP engine does not know if the browser will support it.  You could, however, fire an ajax call in the `onbeforeunload` even that would tell the server it was being fired then pause the exit with a prompt/alert dialog.

This, of course, is not guaranteed to be fired by a browser so its not a reliable practice.